# Testing AG-Grid events in Angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I want to test AG-Grid and fire events like `cellValueChanged`, `cellEditingStarted` in angular. Can anybody tell, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This work for me.

```js
component.gridOptions.api.startEditingCell({
    rowIndex: 0, // row number to edit
    colKey: 'edit_field_name'
})
const editCell = component.gridOptions.api
    .getCellEditorInstances()[0]
    .getGui()
    .querySelector('.ag-cell-edit-input') as HTMLInputElement

editCell.value = 'value to set'
component.gridOptions.api.stopEditing()
fixture.detectChanges()
```